# Jquery - toggle problem

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this toggle function

```
$('#togglebtn').toggle(function() {
 $('#panel').show();
}, function() {
 $('#panel').hide();
});
```

I also have another button to close/hide the panel

```
$('#otherbtn').click(function() {
 $('#panel').hide();
});
```

All I am trying to say is that when I hide the panel with `#otherbtn` the event is still active on `#togglebtn` and gives me an extra click to start toggle the panel again. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger click event on toggle button.

```
$('#otherbtn').click(function() {
 $('#panel').hide();
 $('#togglebtn').click(); //resets tooglebtn state
});
```

Comment: The #otherbtn is inside #panel

Comment: So? Have you tried the code? When you click on #otherbtn function will be executed.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is already available via the other [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function. Just bind it to the `click` event:

```
$('#togglebtn').click(function() {
    $('#panel').toggle()
});
```

*(instead of `$('#togglebtn').toggle(...)` )*

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#otherbtn').click(function() {
 $('#panel').hide();
$('#togglebtn').toggle(function() {
 $('#panel').hide();
}, function() {
 $('#panel').show();
});

});
```

Should work. Reversed the toggle behaviour of the 'otherbtn'

Comment: This will bind the functions as click event handlers to `#togglebtn` every time you click `#otherbtn`. Granted, it will have the desired effect, but you will end up with a lot of unnecessary click event handlers. This is definitely **not** the right way.

Comment: The #otherbtn is inside #panel